# Set all the pages layout to elementor full width

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Facing some challenges in changing the default theme page layouts to elementor full width.

A single post or single page layouts are unable to be accessed for changing the layout structure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling Elementor?
Try it.
If it doesn't solve the problem, simply recreate them with elementor or you can just use wp plugins.

Comment: Hi Atiq,
 Page layouts for single post or single pages you mean?

Answer (score 0):

A Full-Width Page means the content spans from right to left and takes the full 100% of the screen's width.

With Elementor there numerous ways to do this, here are three:

1. Use a Full-Width page template
2. Use the Canvas page template
3. Stretch the sections.

Details of the explanation can be found here: https://docs.elementor.com/article/40-full-width-page

Hope this maybe of your help, Please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. 
For example: A blog page is created for viewing all blogs and set to elementor full width. For viewing a single blog page the page layout is set to default themes orientation. I'm unable to change for the single page layouts.

Comment: have you tried this option: https://pasteboard.co/ISkQpqm.jpg during the creation of single post/page template ? There is a option of stretching the width to full. If your problem still exist can you please elaborate a bit with screenshot

Comment: 1. https://pasteboard.co/ISldZ5y.png :  This is a page where all the blogs are uploaded, so I’ve put elementor full width, so that I’m just using header and footer of the theme. 

2.. https://pasteboard.co/ISleyzMj.png  :  This is inside one of the blog (What I refer as a single page) I’m unable to find how to change the default theme layout to elementor full width, so that automatically created pages follow the same fashion.

Comment: well I have gone through few ways but I think there is no way to set a custom template as default for your single post. Elementor have different add-ons like anywhere elementor, this may work in your case. Also programmatically you can use a wordpress filter to serve your needs : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/. 
Please let me know if you find any alternate solution.